# Is there any reason to list standard library dependencies when using setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

I've gone down the Python packaging and distribution rabbit-hole and am wondering:

> Is there ever any reason to provide standard library modules/packages as dependencies to `setup()` when using `setuptools`?

And a side note: [the only `setuptools` docs I have found are terrible](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).  Is there anything better?

Thanks

Comment: The currently-recommended docs for all (beginning) things Python packaging is https://packaging.python.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No** — In fact, you should *never* specify standard modules as `setup()` requirements, because those requirements are only for downloading packages from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org) (or VCS repositories or other package indices).  Adding, say, `"itertools"` to `install_requires` will mean that your package will fail to install because its dependencies can't be satisfied because [there's (currently) no package named "itertools" on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/itertools).  Some standard modules do share their name with a project on PyPI; in the best case (e.g., [argparse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse)), the PyPI project is compatible with the standard module and only exists as a separate project for historical reasons/backwards compatibility.  In the worst case... well, use your imagination.

Answer (score 5):

In a word, **no**.  The point of the dependencies is to make sure they are available when someone installs your library.  Since standard libraries are always available with a python installation, you do not need to include them.

For a more user-friendly guide to packaging, check out Hynek's guide:
[Sharing Your Labor of Love: PyPI Quick and Dirty](https://hynek.me/articles/sharing-your-labor-of-love-pypi-quick-and-dirty/)